# Positive lookbehind with optional

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get Name without `~`, `<` and `>`. So far I have `(?<=<)[^>]+` and `(?<=<[~]*)[^>]+` doesn't seem to work as I hoped.

```
[Info] Type: (Subject) {Id} <~Name> /command *All characters possible here*
[Info] Type: (Subject) {Id} <Name> /command *All characters possible here*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second pattern almost works, you might add a word boundary after matching an optional ~

```
(?<=<~?\b)[^>]+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3c%7e%3f%5cb%29%5b%5e%3e%5d%2b&i=%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3c%7eName%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*%0d%0a%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3cName%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*)

If you want to match any character after it, look back assering a `<` not looking at `~` or looking back at `<~`

```
(?<=<(?!~)|<~)[^>]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert directly to the left

  - `<(?!~)` Match `<` not looking at `~`
  - `|` Or
  - `<~` Match `<~`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^>]+` Match 1+ times any char except `>`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3c%28%3f!%7e%29%7c%3c%7e%29%5b%5e%3e%5d%2b&i=%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3c%7eName%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*%0d%0a%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3cName%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*%0d%0a%0d%0a%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3c%40%23%25%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*%0d%0a%0d%0a%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3c%7e%40%23%25%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*%0d%0a%0d%0a%5bInfo%5d+Type%3a+%28Subject%29+%7bId%7d+%3c%3e+%2fcommand+*All+characters+possible+here*)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"<[^\w<>]*([^>]+)>")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%5B%5E%5Cw%3C%3E%5D*%28%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B%29%3E&i=%5BInfo%5D%20Type%3A%20%28Subject%29%20%7BId%7D%20%3C%7EName%3E%20%2Fcommand%20*All%20characters%20possible%20here*%0D%0A%5BInfo%5D%20Type%3A%20%28Subject%29%20%7BId%7D%20%3CName%3E%20%2Fcommand%20*All%20characters%20possible%20here*). With this regex, the value you need is in Group 1. Also, see the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%3C%5B%5E%5Cw%3C%3E%5D*(%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B)%3E):

[image]

*Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `[^\w<>]*` - zero or more chars other than word and `<` / `>` delimiter chars
- `([^>]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

If you need to get the match text without capturing, in this case, you might try using

```cs
(?<=<[^\w<>]*)\b[^>]+
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3C%5B%5E%5Cw%3C%3E%5D*%29%5Cb%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B&i=%5BInfo%5D%20Type%3A%20%28Subject%29%20%7BId%7D%20%3C%7EName%3E%20%2Fcommand%20*All%20characters%20possible%20here*%0D%0A%5BInfo%5D%20Type%3A%20%28Subject%29%20%7BId%7D%20%3CName%3E%20%2Fcommand%20*All%20characters%20possible%20here*). *Details*:

- `(?<=<[^\w<>]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `<` followed with zero or more chars other than word and delimiter chars (`<` and `>`)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^>]+` - one or more chars other than `>`.